# BigQuery SQL to add metadata to a column

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

Currently, I have a BigQuery table with the following schema:

| region | node_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 2, 3, 4] |
| 2 | [5, 6, 7, 8] |

Where node_ids is a column of `array<int64>` in BigQuery.

I have another table which contains a mapping from each node_id to the number of errors in that node and it looks something like this.

| node_id | errors |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 9 |
| 7 | 10 |
| 8 | 6 |

I want to use this secondary table to augment the first table with error values. Specifically, I'd like to turn node_ids into an `array<struct<int64, int64>>` where each node_id also has with it the number of errors.

I'm not sure how to do this in BigQuery SQL. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select region, array_agg(struct(node_id, errors)) node_ids
from regions r,
r.node_ids node_id
join mapping 
using(node_id) 
group by region
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

and resulted schema is

[image]

Another options is to avoid unnesting and then grouping  - do mapping just on row level

```
select region, array(
    select as struct node_id, errors
    from r.node_ids node_id
    join mapping 
    using(node_id) 
  ) node_ids
from regions r
```

Obviously with exactly same output